# Why does MSDN documentation show protected methods for Random?

Tags: c#, .net

I've been reading on the MSDN .Net Framework Class Library and I found out something....

For example when you read the `System.Random` class documentation we are given information about the Protected Random.Class Methods.

How is that information going to help us or can we override those methods like ToString()?

Comment: I read your "question" and all I can come up with is: huh?

Comment: What exactly you're talking about? Which method?

Comment: If you create a subclass, it's useful to know what protected methods are available for you to call, no?

Comment: The Finalize, MemberwiseClone ,Sample We are given this information how are we going to use this? Isn't this information defying the rules of inheritance, Hiding class implementation from the class user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have several questions about the [System.Random](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation. It lists three protected methods, but two of them are inherited from `System.Object`. The third one is `Sample`, which is documented to return "a random floating-point number between 0.0 and 1.0."

To answer your title question, no, the MSDN documentation is not incorrect. That method does exist, and it does what it says.

You also ask "can we override those methods...?" Yes, we can. `System.Random` is not a sealed class, so we can inherit it, and `Sample` is overridable, so we can override it. Even if it were not overridable, it would still need to be documented, because a class inheriting `Random` might need to access it.

So to your question "how is that information going to help us," it helps in several ways. If you create a class that inherits `System.Random`, you may need documentation on its protected methods, so that you know how to use (or override) those methods. If you are a framework developer, and are troubleshooting a bug in `System.Random`, you may need documentation on its internal implementation.

Also, the MSDN documentation is in the same format as a lot of other documentation, which is auto-generated from XML comments in the code. If MSDN documentation is similarly auto-generated, then it would be a big job to go through the entire framework and selectively hide things on a case-by-case basis, even if it were desirable to do so.

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Overriding shows how and why you might derive from `System.Random` in order to substitute your own algorithm.